# CoreML LSTM input doesn't match Keras input shape

Tags: keras, coreml, coremltools

I'm trying to convert a very simple keras model to CoreML, however, the inputs of the CoreML model don't seem to match my expectations.

The model I'm creating has an input shape of (5, 10) (five timesteps, 10 features), however, after converting the model, and opening the model in Xcode, it says the input type is `MultiArray (Double 10)`, which, from my understanding is a single dimensional array. My question is, what am i doing wrong? Is there a way to tell CoreML that the input is specifically 5x10?

Here's the keras model I'm creating

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense

length = 5
n_features = 10
out_index = 2

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(25, input_shape=(length, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(n_features, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

I run the following code to convert the model

```
import coremltools
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model)
coreml_model.save("Echo.mlmodel")
```

In Xcode, you can see the inputs that it interpreted from the model 
[image: Xcode CoreML input output]

Edit (01/12/20):

I tried to be smart, and just edit the coreml model directly in python,

```
coreml_model._spec.description.input[0].type.multiArrayType.shape[:] = [1, 5, 10]
```

Unfortunately, this causes compile errors in Xcode
[image: Xcode compilation error]

Also for reference, here are the library versions my notebook is running:

```
keras 2.2.5
tensorflow 1.15.0
coremltools 3.1
```

Comment: which backend you are using with keras, tensorflow ??

Comment: Yes, I believe its using a tensorflow backend. I'm running my code in google colab

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, it looks like that input "type" label is a little misleading. Although it says `MultiArray (Double 10)`, it's actually accepts a multi dimensional array. The caveat here is the shape of the array.

Whereas with Keras, I might pass in an array of size `(1, 5, 10)` (i.e. `(batch, timestemps, features)` when running `predict`, with CoreML, you have to transpose the input to match `(timestep, batch, features)`.

Therefore the right way to interpret the Xcode "type" field, would be to say the input accepts 10 features. The "Description" field (not seen in the screenshot) should be used to describe what the expected array shape should be.